# Dropout, Regularization and batch normalization

Tags: keras, lstm

I have a couple of questions about LSTM layers in Keras library

In LSTM layer we have two kind of dropouts: dropout and recurrent-dropout. According to my understanding the first one will drop randomly some features from input (set them to zero) and the second one will do it on hidden units (features of h_t). Since we have different time steps in a LSTM network, is dropping applied seperately to each time step or only one time and will be the same for every step?

My second question is about regularizers in LSTM layer in keras. I know that for example the kernel regularizer will regularize weights corresponding to inputs. but we have different weights for inputs.
For example input gate, update gate and output gates use different weights for input (aslo different weights for h_(t-1)) . So will they be regularized in the same time ? What if I want to regularize only one of them? For example if I want to regularize only the weights used in the formula for input gate.

The last question is about activation functions in keras. In LSTM layer I have activation and recurrent activations. activation is tanh by default and I know in LSTM architecture tanh is used two times (for h_t and candidate of memory cell) and sigmoid is used 3 times (for gates). So does that mean if I change tanh (in LSTM layer in keras) to another function say Relu then it will change for both of h_t and memory cell candidate?

It would be perfect if any of those question could be answered. Thank you very much for your time.